# How much healing does Necromacy School ability do?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

> **Healing Grace (Su):**
>
> Whenever you cast a spell that has targets, affects creatures in an
>   area, or requires an attack roll, you may heal creatures affected by
>   the spell a total of 1 point of damage per level of the spell. This
>   healing may be spread out between the targets of the spell in any way
>   you choose. If you assign any of the healing to an undead creature, it
>   instead takes 1 point of damage for each point assigned. At 11th
>   level, the amount of damage cured increases to 2 points of damage per
>   level of the spell. This healing occurs when the spell is cast and has
>   no effect on creatures that enter its area after the spell is in
>   place. At 20th level, the amount of damage cured increases to 3 points
>   of damage per level of the spell.

What does, "may heal creatures affected by the spell a total of 1 point of damage per level of the spell"? Is that literal spell level?

EX: Cantrips = 0 HP, 1st Level = 1 HP, 2nd Level = 2 HP, 3rd Level = 3 HP, etc....

or Damage Dice?

Ex: heal with Shocking Grasp (max 5d8) = 5 HP, Fireball (Max 10d6) = 10 HP

or a 1 to 1 damage per die per spell level?

Ex: heal with Shocking Grasp = 5d6 HP, Fireball = 10d6 HP

Answer (score 7):

It’s the spell level, just as it says. 0 for cantrips, 1 hp for 1st-level spells, and so on. And yes, that is effectively worthless.

Comment: Just for fun, I calculated the maximum healing if you cast ALL of your spells, hitting valid targets that you'd want to heal or harm, except bonus from INT. Maximum healing per day, by level, is 1: 1hp, 2: 2hp, 3: 4hp, 4: 7hp, 5: 10hp, 6: 15hp, 7: 24hp, 8: 27hp, 9: 34hp, 10: 76hp, 11: 104hp, 12: 126hp, 13: 148hp, 14: 174hp, 15: 200hp, 16: 230hp, 17: 260hp, 18: 292hp, 19: 324hp, 20: 537hp